# where condition in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i am trying to fetch data from the table which has some foreign keys by using codeigniter's active records. i haven't get any result. my question is where i'm going wrong here is my code in model.

```
public function fetch_customer()
    {
        $s = 'customer.stb_id';
        $w_array = array('set_top_box.stb_id' => $s );
        $customers = $this->db->select('customer.c_name,customer.acc_no,customer.stb_id,set_top_box.stb_no,customer.mobile_no,customer.subscription_amount,customer.c_status')
                              ->from('customer,set_top_box')
                              ->where($w_array)
                              ->get();
            return $customers->result();
    }
```

Comment: you can't have multiple tables in `from()` you should use `join()` for that. e.g. `$this->db->from('customer c');$this->db->join('set_top_box stb', 'stb.stb_no = c.stb_id')`

Comment: it is possible to use more then one table in from()  AdrienXL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you can not add multiple table name in form () clause you use join() like this

```
public function fetch_customer()
    {
        $s = 'customer.stb_id';
        $w_array = array('set_top_box.stb_id' => $s );
        $customers = $this->db->select('customer.c_name,customer.acc_no,customer.stb_id,set_top_box.stb_no,customer.mobile_no,customer.subscription_amount,customer.c_status')
                              ->from('customer')
                              ->join('set_top_box','here on clause ')  
                              ->where($w_array)
                              ->get();
            return $customers->result();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @Divyesh. it is the right way to fetch data. whats your mail id? im from Ahmedabad also.

Comment: divyesh.trambadia@gmail.com